# my submit form isn't submitting data without clicking on form

Tags: javascript, php, form-submit

is the form below correct ?  I'm trying to submit the form without clicking on the submit button but it doesnt seem to submit the data

```
echo '<form name="myForm" id ="myForm" method="post" action="http://caliberconnect.capna.biz/box.php">';
    echo '<input name="email" type="hidden" id="email" value="$email">';
    echo '<input name="name" type="hidden" id="name" value=" $firstname $lastname">';
    echo '<input name="field1" type="hidden" id="field1" value=" ($phone_areacode) $phone_prefix-$phone_suffix ">';
    echo '<input name="field2" type="hidden" id="field2" value="$practicename">';
    echo '<input name="field3" type="hidden" id="field3" value="">';
    echo '<input name="funcml" type="hidden" id="funcml" value="add">';
    echo '<input name="p" type="hidden" id="p" value="7">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="nlbox[1]" value="31">';
    echo '</form>';

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'document.getElementById("myForm").submit();';
    echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Is there an error? Does it submit or does it just sit there? Is a pop up blocker preventing it?

Comment: How do you know it isn't submitting?  Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: it is supposed to insert stuff in the database ... no error in console

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TemVtt

Comment: @user3530095 There can be several steps between the execution of the `submit()` function (if it is executed) and the insertion of data in your database. You should try to narrow down your problem, see which step is failing.

Answer (score 0):

add a submit button to your form and hide it with css
    `<input type="submit" name="" style="position:absolute;left:-9999px;"/>`

Comment: but the submit form is submitting with javascript .. is the submit button necessary ?

Comment: JavaScript can submit a form without a submit button.

Comment: So my code is fine ?? because I am trying to submit it without hitting the key

Comment: I stand corrected youre right @showdev, I didn't think of his question fully

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding an onLoad event associated to your form and call a function of javascript where you are submitting your form

```
<form onLoad="submitFormOnLoad()">
</form>

function submitFormOnLoad()
{
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Below is the reference for onLoad events.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp